# Check/Validate and reuse CodeIgniter session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a website for my website with 20 api calls (REST). for every call the user/pass input is required.

The API calls can be made from C++, Python, PHP, Java, ASP etc...

the issue I have now is it creates tons of sessions. I want to change this to allow all calls to re-use the session id assigned.

so the first call will be to "authenticate", this return a token (encrypted session id)

then I decrypt this token and check if the session id exists in the database. If it does, i want to load or assign this session

I found a pge from ellislab explaining session but it does not help me since this page creates new session.

example:

call #1: authenticate(user,password)

call #2: get_report(token, 1) // get report id 1

call #3: add_user(token, [array of user data])

How can i reuse the session in codeigniter?

Comment: @RyanVincent I edited my question but yes REST calls from any code (php, java etc...)

Comment: Thanks for the edit to the question - it helps.

Comment: Maybe useful: [RESTful Services with CodeIgniter](http://outergalactic.org/blog/restful-services-with-codeigniter/). Includes a reference to: [CodeIgniter Rest Server](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to save the token in session if not exist.

1) Get the token form your request like username I think user name is unique for you.

2)

```
$this->load->library('session');
$user_data = $this->session->userdata('$username');
if(!empty($user_data)){
//use the same session
}else{
$this->session->set_userdata('$username', 'isvalid');
}
```